# How to add IList<IWebElement> in Arrays Selenium

Tags: arrays, excel, selenium, ilist

I am new to both `C#` and `selenium`.

This is the sample code, it is working fine, I know it's not a standard way of coding but I don't know what is the standard code for this instance.

I have to extract 5000-10000 elements from each string, so is there any fastest and standard code for this, I think my solution will be too slow.

```
IList<IWebElement> ARNum = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("sumXpath1"));
IList<IWebElement> MPNum = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("sumXpath2"));
IList<IWebElement> MGNum = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("sumXpath3"));

int RowARNum=1;
foreach(IWebElement artNum in ARNum) {//for First Column
    RowARNum++;
    XLWorkSheet.Cells(RowARNum, 1) = artNum.Text;
}

int RowMPNum =1;
foreach(IWebElement mpNum in MPNum){ //for Second Column
    RowMPNum++;
    XLWorkSheet.Cells(RowMPNum, 1) = mpNum.Text;
}

int RowMGNum =1;
foreach(IWebElement mgNum in MGNum){ //for Third Column
    RowMGNum++;
    XLWorkSheet.Cells(RowMGNum, 1) = mgNum.Text;
}
```

Comment: What is this doing XLWorkSheet.Cells(RowMGNum, 1)? Adding a row into a Excel worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It should hopefully speed up the processing.

Maybe try and add the `StopWatch()` class to time your implementation compared to mine?

```
        IList<IWebElement> ARNum = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("sumXpath1"));
        IList<IWebElement> MPNum = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("sumXpath2"));
        IList<IWebElement> MGNum = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("sumXpath3"));

        Parallel.For(0, ARNum.Count(), i =>
        {
            XLWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1) = ARNum[i].Text;
        });

        Parallel.For(0, MPNum.Count(), i =>
        {
            XLWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1) = MPNum[i].Text;
        });

        Parallel.For(0, MGNum.Count(), i =>
        {
            XLWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1) = MGNum[i].Text;
        });
```

Comment: S for adding rows in excel @Jamie Rees.....i wll try this and let u knw, if u hav any new suggetions pls let me knw, for writing excel in high speed...thanks for ur reply.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: S tried, iam getting below mentioned error, if i change index value 0 to 1 it wll works better than my code, but it is skipping one value from web page there r 20 elements, but m getting 19 values. And sum one suggested me to use arrays, it may give u faster result i dont knw how to apply in this condition, after this i hav page navigation also challenge. I hope u wll support me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you changed it from 0 to 1 then it would make sense why you are only getting 19 results. It means you are starting the iteration from the index of 0. I'm not sure what your exception is. Please edit your original post to tell me where your exception is being thrown.

Comment: M getting "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC", I guess row number is invalid.

Comment: @TesterCs that is something completly different, maybe you should read up on it. This problem occurs if you are using a backwards compatible sheet (a .xls) instead of a .xlsx. Go to Excel Options > Save > Save Files in this format > Select "Excel Workbook(*.xlsx)".

Comment: S i had changed excel format from xls to xlsx, still m finding same error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Comment: This code am using for xl 
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlWorkBook.SaveAs("E:\\csharp-Excel.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);

Comment: @TesterCs This seems to be going off topic from the original post. If you are having a problem with the spreadsheets I suggest you post a new question. I won't be replying to this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

pls chk this while using ur code
    Iam getting this error,
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code
      HResult=-2146827284
      Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
      Source=""
      ErrorCode=-2146827284
      StackTrace:
           at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
           at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set__Default(Object RowIndex, Object ColumnIndex, Object value)
           at CDP_Win.Form1.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__2(Int32 i) in e:\MyProjects\CDP_Win - Copy\CDP_Win\Form1.cs:line 115
           at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__c()
      InnerException: 
    @Jamie Rees , @Mark Rowlands